# How can the universe be homogeneous and isotropic while it has started with a big bang?

Tags: cosmology, symmetry, universe, space-expansion, big-bang

We assume the universe has been shaped by a explosion "Big Bang" but from what I understand explosions make the environment "not" homogeneous and "not" isotropic.
If that's right how can we assume the universe is homogeneous and isotropic?
or am I wrong about the meaning of homogeneous and isotropic?

Comment: That's true if the "explosion" happens in one particular place in space , but since the Big Bang happened everywhere in space, this does not apply here.

Comment: It's inflation that makes the universe homogeneous and isotropic.

Comment: This question, not exactly for the reasons you stated, though, is a current research topic.